# Remove Simple Hook on Genesis Framework

Tags: wordpress, genesis

I use Visual Hook plugin to add a hook position to my site - "genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap". However, when I create a new page (landing page - an empty page), while everything is gone, the new hook is still there.

I went to ***page_landing.php*** and want to add remove_action code to remove genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap. I'm not sure what to add here.

I tried:

```
remove_action('genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap');
```

I doesn't work. Please help. Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to put a condition to the simple hook plugin configuration page.

```
<?php if( !is_page('page-name')) { ?>

//the code goes here

<?php } ?>
```

And it shows to every pages but not the ***page-name***.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help

Add following code to your `functions.php`

```
add_action( 'genesis_meta', 'remove_sidebar_from_pages' );
/**
 * Remove sidebar from pages
*/
function remove_sidebar_from_pages() {
    if( is_page_template( 'page_landing.php' ) )
    {
        // Remove default genesis sidebars
        remove_action( 'genesis_after_content', 'genesis_get_sidebar' );
        remove_action( 'genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap', 'genesis_get_sidebar_alt');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, this one remove from every pages, not the blank landing page (page_landing.php) - a feature of genesis framework.

Comment: @DaleNguyen Are you try add to your page_landing.php `remove_action( 'genesis_after_content', 'genesis_get_sidebar' );
        remove_action( 'genesis_after_content_sidebar_wrap', 'genesis_get_sidebar_alt');`

Comment: Yes, it's still there :(

Comment: @DaleNguyen `if( is_page_template( 'page_landing.php' ) )` Replaced this? :(

Comment: Hi, I found an acceptable solution for this. Check it out :)

Comment: @DaleNguyen Okay bro. xD Congratulate bro xD